# How I can read and store the replies form Web activity (Post) - Azure datafactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

How I can read and store in database the replies form Web activity (Post)  . I would to check that post was successful

Please see attached the image for more easy detail

[image]

[image]
Thanks so much for your help
Javier

Answer (score 0):

Two conditions:

1.If you just judging the result of POST request for the next execution of activity, you could use the success dependency to connect the following activities.

[image]

2.If you want to persist the result of POST request, even send notification to you, please consider using [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) to accept the output of Web Activity[`@activity('Web1').output`]. Pass the output to Azure Function and implement the requirements with code in the Azure Function inside.

Comment: Thanks Jay... But I need to move the results from POST to database

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case is better to user the Copy Data activity (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview), there you can define your Source Dataset and your Sink Dataset.

In your case the Source will be the HTTP request and the Sink will be the database, any type of the ones offer by Azure.

Please take into consideration the pagination support from the Copy Data activity.

Take care.